# Оксид, окись и окисел

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто в неспециальной литературе встречаю слова "окись" и "окисел". Я учил химию в университете, но никаких окисей и окислов мы не учили - были только оксиды и закиси, поэтому вышеприведенные слова кажутся мне неграмотными. Прав ли я?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oкисел.
Значение:
хим. устар. то же, что оксид. 
Окись.
Значение:
хим. устар. то же, что оксид.